# Unable to start payara from eclipse

Tags: java, enterprise, payara

Windows 10, JDK 1.8 or 15, eclipse 2021-06, maven project HelloWorld.
I installed payara tools from eclipse marketplace.
Starting payara server gives error message:

"Launching Payara Server on Felix platform
ERROR: Error parsing system bundle statement.
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exported package names cannot be zero length."

Answer (score 0):

> Any suggestions on alternative server to use?

Have you tried just downloading the Payara Server full from their site and running it directly. You could then install and update war files using hot deploy folder.

Another alternative is to run Payara server in docker with docker-compose. Just create folder somewhere and create docker-compose.yml with following contents to it.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3.1'
   
  services:     
    # Full payara application-server
    payara-server-full:
      container_name: payara-server-full
      image: payara/server-full:5.2021.1
      ports:
        - 8080:8080 # HTTP listener
        - 8443:8443 # HTTPS listener
        - 6900:6900 # Hazelcast cluster communication port
        - 4848:4848 # admin console. localhost:4848 (user:admin pw:admin)
      volumes:
        # persist auto-deployments
        - payara-domain1:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/ 
        # startup deployment
        - ./payara/deployments:/opt/payara/deployments:z 
        # war-files in this folder will be auto-deployed to payara
        - ./payara/autodeploy:/opt/payara/appserver/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy:z 
    
  volumes:
    payara-domain1
```

**Usage:**

```sh
# Startup
docker-compose up -d

# Shutdown
docker-compose down

# Remove the volume to clean up or start fresh
docker volumes rm payara-domain1
```

One simple way to auto-deploy using maven-war-plugin.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>***path-to-autodeploy**</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for input, but I've switched to using the tomcat 9.0 server, which starts OK.  I did download payara dircectly as you suggested, but I'm not familiar with docker.

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the "README.TXT" of Payara Server -> Currently supports for JVM, JDK8, JDK11.

Just follow these steps:
File > New > Other... > (Folder) Server > Server

Click on Next

Select the server type: Payara

(If you have previous runtime configurations, delete them)
So now, Select the Payara location folder, and Java location (Choose jdk-11 folder) --> Eclipse may give you a default path as .p2... don't use that one, use the path of your jdk-11.

Then you can choose the name, your domain path, debug credentials and click finish.

Now you can right-click > start on your payara server and its should works.

You can also check localhost:4848 on the web browser.